# compilation using roslyn and modifications on the fly

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I've seen a lot of people talk about the Roslyn compiler and its ability to compile as a service. There's a feature in Java when developing in Eclipse (not sure if it's only Eclipse) that allows you to modify the code without stopping or pausing the application. This is really useful when debugging render in games (that's what I use it for). Will the new abilities that Roslyn brings allow such a thing in .Net development?

Comment: The has nothing to do with Roslyn, the feature is called Edit-and-Continue and has been around for ages... Edit: Granted, it is not always as reliable as the Java equivalent.

Comment: I'm aware of edit and continue, but it requires pausing the execution... Or perhaps there is a way to do it without stopping that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I don't quite understand this question.  What I think you are saying is that you literally modify the code, while the code is running (not debugging at a break point etc).  If that is the case, I don't believe that feature exists now or will be introduced in the next Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the new abilities that Roslyn brings allow such a thing in .Net development?

No, Roslyn is still mostly a traditional compiler: code comes in and an assembly (.exe or .dll) comes out.

What's different with Roslyn is that it lets you manipulate code. But it doesn't do anything regarding manipulating assemblies, which I think would be required for what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Because of dynamic compilation we can just make the changes in the code and need to just refresh the browser to reflect our changes.In the previous versions of ASP.NET we have to make code changes then re-build the solution and then refresh the browser for our changes to take effect.

Now we can just change make the code change and  refresh the browser for our change to reflect.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/835251/Overview-of-ASP-NET-vNext